# Explanation for 'sed'

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a huge text file called helo.lst in which every line starts with the format:

```
#=GS N4TFW2_FUSC1/96-161      AC N4TFW21
```

I'm only interested in the `N4TFW2_FUSC1` part. I need to extract this part from the rest of the text and apply the same for the whole text file.

I found out that the following script works but I couldn't get how.

```
cat helo.lst | sed 's/^#=GS\s\([A-Z0-9_]*\)\/.*/\1/1' > helo_id.lst
```

Can someone explain what's going on after `s/`

AFAIK, for example `sed 's/Mark/Euro/g' de_currency.txt`changes every occurrences of `Mark` with `Euro` in the `de_currency.txt` file. But in my example the script looks more complicated than this.

Comment: 's[search]/[what to search for]/[what to replace it with]/g'[global -- if you want it to replace every occurrence per line or only the first -- without the g]. The slashes are delimiters and can just as easily be replaced with other characters such as `@`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per sed syntax:

/original/substitution/1 time

---

*breaking down original*

^  beginning of line

#=GS string to search

\s space

(   )  \ to take meaning from ( as is used in shell ; () to denote     variable to be substituted in the substitution part (grouping)

[A-Z0-9_] [] is for one char, that can be from A to Z, 0 to 9, and _

* means 0 or more times

\/  as \ is to take meaning of it from the shell, it represents the string ending with "/"

.* consume/match everything else until the end of line

---

breaking down substitution

\1 first string regexp match (variable) in the original string (back reference [to grouping])

---

Warning: this is GNU sed syntax. If in OS/X or *BSD, you have to use gsed

Link to  sed article about advanced examples:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/unix-sed-tutorial-advanced-sed-substitution-examples/